# Type check for iterator?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following line of code in my project:

```
Iterator<Node> i = graph.nodes();
```

graph.nodes() is a method defined in prefuse.

Now I want to add a type check to the iterator, but how can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by type check? When you start iterating it will throw `ClassCastException` if `graph.nodes` contains not `Node`.

Comment: I want to avoid that, because I now there are only nodes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you could do

```
Iterator<Node> iterator = Iterators.filter(theOriginalIterator, Node.class);
```

The returned iterator is guaranteed to continue only elements that correspond to the supplied type. ( A similar method is also available for [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) btw )

See

- [`Iterators.filter(iterator, class)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#filter%28java.util.Iterator,%20java.lang.Class%29)
- [`Iterables.filter(iterable, class)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29)